# The problem of the applicaion keep stopping

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have faced the problem of my application always show keep stopping. I try to see the terminal and it show me the problem is not been initialized. However, I have found many ways but still cannot show it. Can somebody help me? Thank for your help

Below are my original code which problem out :

```html
package com.example.assignment_mad

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.example.assignment_mad.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_notification_.*


class Notification_Fragment : Fragment( ) {

    private lateinit var newRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var newArrayList: ArrayList<Company>
    private lateinit var tempArrayList: ArrayList<Company>
    lateinit var imageId:Array<Int>
    lateinit var heading:Array<String>
    lateinit var news:Array<String>



    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.MyViewHolder>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_, container, false)


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(itemView: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        imageId= arrayOf(
            R.drawable.company_logo_1,
            R.drawable.company_logo_2,
            R.drawable.company_logo_3,
            R.drawable.company_logo_4,
            R.drawable.company_logo_5,
            R.drawable.company_logo_6,
            R.drawable.company_logo_7,
            R.drawable.company_logo_8,
            R.drawable.company_logo_9,
            R.drawable.company_logo_10
        )

        heading= arrayOf(
            "Candidate Biden Called Saudi Arable a Pareft eaft.",
            "The definitive text on the healing powers of the mind/body connection.",
            "This is the definitive book on mindfulness from the beloved Zen master.",
            "A timeless classic in personal development.",
            "The definitive text on the healing powers of the mind/body connection.",
            "The definitive text on the healing powers of the mind/body connection.",
            "The definitive text on the healing powers of the mind/body connection.",
            "The definitive text on the healing powers of the mind/body connection.",
            "The definitive text on the healing powers of the mind/body connection.",
            "The definitive text on the healing powers of the mind/body connection."
        )

        news= arrayOf(
            getString(R.string.news_a),
            getString(R.string.news_b),
            getString(R.string.news_c),
            getString(R.string.news_d),
            getString(R.string.news_e),
            getString(R.string.news_f),
            getString(R.string.news_g),
            getString(R.string.news_h),
            getString(R.string.news_i),
            getString(R.string.news_j)
        )


        newArrayList= arrayListOf<Company>()
        tempArrayList= arrayListOf<Company>() //it show here get error
        getUserdata()

        super.onViewCreated(itemView, savedInstanceState)

        newRecyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            newRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
            newRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        }

        recyclerView.apply {
            // set a LinearLayoutManager to handle Android
            // RecyclerView behavior
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            // set the custom adapter to the RecyclerView
            adapter = NotificationAdapter(newArrayList)
        }


    }


    private fun getUserdata() {
        for (i in imageId.indices){
            val company=Company(imageId[i],heading[i])
            newArrayList.add(company)
        }


        newRecyclerView.adapter=NotificationAdapter(newArrayList) //it show here get error
  
    }


}
```

Below are my problem showing out :

```html
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property newRecyclerView has not been initialized
        at com.example.assignment_mad.Notification_Fragment.getUserdata(Notification_Fragment.kt:122)
        at com.example.assignment_mad.Notification_Fragment.onViewCreated(Notification_Fragment.kt:89)
```

Below are my Notification Adapter :

```html
package com.example.assignment_mad

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView

class NotificationAdapter(private val companyList:ArrayList<Company>): RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var mListener:onItemClickListener

    interface onItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: onItemClickListener){
        mListener=listener
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView=
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView,mListener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem=companyList[position]
        holder.titleImage.setImageResource(currentItem.titleImage)
        holder.tvHeading.text=currentItem.heading
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return companyList.size
    }

    //to insert the post detail
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: onItemClickListener): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val titleImage: ShapeableImageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
        val tvHeading: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i think i not really understand what it stated above

Answer (score 0):

Try to findViewById before apply

```
     override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
        var views = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_, container, false)
        newRecyclerView=views.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        
        return views 
    }

...

     newRecyclerView.apply {
         layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity)
         newRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            }
```

Comment: Thank for your commed. But i try it before, but it seem that cannot not put findViewById in the fragment page. If put above newRecyclerView, it will show error and required to add new function for this.

Comment: @Alexong check my edited answer, change your 'onCreateView'